# sparql slow if more object value specified

Tags: sparql, virtuoso, triplestore

Using virtuoso 7 open source edition,

This query below is fast, it return the result instantly,

```
select *
                WHERE {

                graph <http://localhost:8890/graph> {

                            ?catAtt qq:catId ?catId;
                            qq:caDataType ?caDataType;
                            qq:showInView   ?showInview;
                            qq:valFormat    ?valFormatKey;
                            qq:multiple     ?multiple; 
                            qq:position     ?position; 
                            qq:link         ?link; 
                            qq:catAttName   ?catAttName; 
                            qq:setting      ?setting; 
                            qq:flag         ?flag;
                            qq:unit         ?caUnit.

                   

       
                  }  
                }
                
                
                LIMIT 20
```

This query is so slow, took 10 seconds for the result, the only difference is the ?catId is replaced with literal value 1

```
select *
                WHERE {

                graph <http://localhost:8890/graph> {

                            ?catAtt qq:catId 1;
                            qq:caDataType ?caDataType;
                            qq:showInView   ?showInview;
                            qq:valFormat    ?valFormatKey;
                            qq:multiple     ?multiple; 
                            qq:position     ?position; 
                            qq:link         ?link; 
                            qq:catAttName   ?catAttName; 
                            qq:setting      ?setting; 
                            qq:flag         ?flag;
                            qq:unit         ?caUnit.

                   

       
                  }  
                }
                
                
                LIMIT 20
```

Why is it so ? I am still new in sparql and triplestore, seems like I have to do some indexing on the object ?

EDIT :

I have tried creating the GOPS index with, I don't understand about the Partition part, is using O correct ? What does that partition mean ? Creating this index has improved the execution for the second query to 4 seconds, but still too slow for a DBMS.

```
CREATE COLUMN INDEX RDF_QUAD_GOPS
  ON RDF_QUAD (G, O, P, S)
  PARTITION (O VARCHAR (-1, 0hexffff));
```

Comment: indexing on the permutations is used by many triple stores. Virtuoso does also have some enabled by default, though not `gops` : http://docs.openlinksw.com/virtuoso/rdfperfrdfscheme/ -  nevertheless the behavior is strange, in theory the second query should be "easier". You could "explain" the query although it's pretty hard to understand the debug output for non devs. Anyways, the Openlin mailing list could be a more promising source of support: https://sourceforge.net/p/virtuoso/mailman/virtuoso-users/

Comment: indeed you could try to add another index `gops` - just check the documentation in the first link of my previous comment

Comment: @UninformedUser Hi, thanks, I have tried creating the index, see my question edit, it reduced to 4 seconds now but still pretty slow. I think the same too, considering the second query is more specific but in actual it's slower. I will try to ask help on the mailing list. Btw, does triplet stored in the regular RDBMS table ? in the table DB.DBA.RDF_QUAD ? So virtuoso does not have a native storage of graph ? Or what I don't understand ?

Answer (score 1):

See the following response to this issue on the OpenLink Community Forum https://community.openlinksw.com/t/sparql-slow-if-more-object-value-specified/2064/2 ... post all further questions there ....